# Getting values of an object from an array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There's an object holding items and prices from a grocery store:

```
let groceryStore = {
    'Banana' : .25,
    'Apple' : .30,
    'Lettuce' : 1.20,
    'Onion' : .15,
    'Celery' : 1.15,
    'Garlic' : 1.00,
    'Tomato' : .50
}
```

You have an array of keys:

```
let groceryList = ['Tomato', 'Lettuce', 'Garlic', 'Onion']
```

I now need to find the total of all the values to the keys in my array(groceryList).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take an array, and reduce it to another values, you can usually use the aptly named `Array.reduce()`. Usually to sum an array of numbers, you reduce the array, and add each number to the accumulator (`sum` in the example):

```
arrayOfNumbers.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0)
```

In your case, reduce the array of keys, and take the values from the object using the `key`:

```js
const groceryStore = {
  'Banana': .25,
  'Apple': .30,
  'Lettuce': 1.20,
  'Onion': .15,
  'Celery': 1.15,
  'Garlic': 1.00,
  'Tomato': .50
}

const groceryList = ['Tomato', 'Lettuce', 'Garlic', 'Onion']

const result = groceryList.reduce((sum, key) => sum + groceryStore[key], 0)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Like a charm.  Thank you